# Iphone app getting slow after sometime,how to make it work?

Tags: iphone

I've made a game in objective-C for iphone and is getting slow after playing it for 20- 30 times.I am using 3 timers but i am also releasing them.I am allocating 9 UIImageViews but again releasing them also. Please help?

Comment: Sorry, but there is nowhere near enough information to give you an answer here.  You need to at least post some code so we can see what you are doing.

Comment: Yes, "my application is getting slow" is way too little to work off of.  When you run Shark against your application where is it spending the most time?  What does the CPU Sampler in Instruments tell you?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Instruments to look for any other memory leaks or performance issues?

Comment: yes i've tried everything from performance tool console and crash logs and i've found no leaks still the app getting slow.

Comment: Maybe some other processes are making it slow? Is your iPhone jailbroken with custom software?